# Unable to access PS object from Get-FileHash

Tags: powershell

I have this code.  I thought I could access the $fileHash object and then see each value, i.e. $fileHash.Hash - however this doesn't produce any results?

Any idea why please:

```
$files = get-childitem -recurse -path "D:\files"
foreach ($file in $files)
{
 $fileHash =  Get-FileHash $file.PSPath -Algorithm MD5 | Format-Table
 $fileHash.Hash
}
```

Comment: Replace `$fileHash = Get-FileHash $file.PSPath -Algorithm MD5 | Format-Table` with `(Get-FileHash $file -Algorithm MD5).Hash` then remove the line `$fileHash.Hash`.

Answer (score 0):

Found out why, need to include it in brackets

```
$fileHash =  (Get-FileHash $file.PSPath -Algorithm MD5)
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `( )` - what fixed it for you was the removal of `| Format-Table`.